# I have a grid with 3 rows and 2 columns. How do I make the entire first column only as wide as the longest text?

Tags: html, css, css-grid, max-content

I've looked at answers to similar questions, but none seem to work.

In my current code, the first column in all three rows are all different widths. I want the entire first column in all three rows to be the same width and only as wide as the longest text.

I have tried to no avail:
`grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;`
`grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr;`
`grid-template-columns: fit-content 1fr;`
`grid-template-columns: minmax(auto, 1fr) 1fr;`
`grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));`
`grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, 1fr));`

```css
    .tableRow {
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: none;
    }
    .tableRow:hover, .tableRow:focus {
    background: #eee;
    outline: none;
    }
    .tableRow:last-child {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .tableRow a:not(.tableRowLink) {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .tableCell {
    padding: 18px;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    align-content: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    }
    .tableCell:last-of-type {
    border-right: none;
    }
    
    .tableRowLink {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="tableRow">
    <div class="tableCell"><a href="https://www.link.com/" target="_blank"><p>Link.com</p></a></div>
    <div class="tableCell"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p></div>
    <a class="tableRowLink" href="https://www.link.com/" target="_blank"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="tableRow">
      <div class="tableCell"><a href="https://www.link-link.com/" target="_blank"><p>Link-Link.com</p></a></div>
      <div class="tableCell"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p></div>
      <a class="tableRowLink" href="https://www.link-link.com/" target="_blank"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="tableRow">
      <div class="tableCell"><a href="https://www.link-link-link.com/" target="_blank"><p>Link-Link-Link.com</p></a></div>
      <div class="tableCell"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p></div>
      <a class="tableRowLink" href="https://www.link-link-link.com/" target="_blank"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are ou stuck with that HTML layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you have named your classes, you need to use a table layout. I have updated the HTML a little so you don't have to use the same link twice but the below can also work with your actual HTML

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: none;
}
.tableRow {
  display: table-row;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.tableCell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 18px;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.tableRow:hover,
.tableRow:focus {
  background: #eee;
}
.tableCell:first-child {
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap; /* disable wrapping */
  text-decoration: underline;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.tableCell:last-child {
  color: #000;
  width: 100%; /* force second column to take the maximum of space */
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <a class="tableRow" href="https://www.link.com/" target="_blank">
    <div class="tableCell">
        <p>Link.com</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tableCell">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="tableRow" href="https://www.link-link.com/" target="_blank">
    <div class="tableCell" >
        <p>Link-Link.com</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tableCell">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="tableRow" href="https://www.link-link-link.com/" target="_blank">
    <div class="tableCell">
        <p>Link-Link-Link.com</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tableCell">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <a class="tableRowLink" href="https://www.link-link-link.com/" target="_blank"></a>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: How did you make that to auto adjust the width of all first column according to the with of the longest text?

Comment: @Sarath14Kumar the use of width: 100% on the second column combined with white-space: nowrap on the first one